# Galaxy Store register app - How do I register my apps?

Tags: tizen, samsung-galaxy, samsung-galaxy-gear, samsung

I have an android host app (.apk) and a galaxy watch companion app (tizen), they use SAP to communicate with each other. Both apps are ready.

**Can anyone please provide detailed information on how do I register them on Galaxy Store?** Please. I already read all documents from samsung that I found. I already tried to contact them for help. I already tried samsung's forum. I already tried to upload the apps... I do not know how...

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to register as a developer in the developer portal.
https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-store/discover-galaxy-store.html

The detailed process is also explained well in the following link.
https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-games/get-started-in-galaxy-store.html

Comment: Hey, I am already registered there, and I already have lots of apps registered there... The problem is that the apps registered are standalone apps. I never registered a companion/host app, and I'm having a hard time. I read all docs, incluiding the ones you send.